# Laravel 4 - How to know if request was from admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my application there are two forms for registering a product. This form in on home page and inside the admin panel (users can register and the admin also. This is needed because when an user register something, the admin needs to approve, but in the admin panel you can approve directly).

I use the same route and the same controller method for the two forms. Everything works ok, but i want to know if the controller method was called from the admin panel or from the home page, because i want to redirect to another page both in home and in admin instead of using `Redirect::back()`.

I tried to use `if (Request::is('admin/*'))` but since I use the same route, there is no "admin" in the request.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: How do you know if a user is an admin in order to give them access to that form? It's far better/secure to use that as a way of checking, anything else is potentially spoofable by a malicious user.

Comment: I'm sure you somehow have stored if the user is admin. Try accessing that information by doing `Auth::user()->isAdmin`

Comment: I didn't thought about that. It works fine, the only flaw is that if the admin register a product in the home page instead of the admin panel, he will be redirected to the admin panel instead of the other page. But that's kind a rare scenario. Thanks!

Comment: @PietroCoelho So that means the URL isn't the same? It might help if you show me your routes...

Comment: both forms use the same route ('products.save') but the url is different (in home it's /product/new and in the admin panel is /admin/product/new)

Comment: @PietroCoelho in case that you want Admin to be redirected back after posting the product, in the controller you can put Return redirect::back() instead of redirecting to an exact route.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way_

```
if ($_POST) {
    if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin'){
        redirect();
    }
}
```